# Calculate center coordinates of circles surrounding a larger circle

Tags: geometry, circles

I want to draw, say, 8 smaller circles that are adjacent to the big circle the edge of a big circle, similar to this picture.
[image]

I know the center coordinates of the bigger circle $(A, B)$, its radius $(R)$,radius of the smaller circles $(r)$, and the number of circles I want to draw $(n)$.

My question is very similar to the one discussed [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991430/how-to-get-center-coordinates-of-circles-on-edge-bigger-circle), with one exception. I want a formula that calculates center  coordinates of circles adjacent,  not those on the edge of a bigger circle.
Mathematics is not my strongest side (to say the least), so I'd greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: I think $n$ determines $r$, so for example if you want $6$ externally tangent circles then $r$ is fixed at $r=R$ (all $7$ circles are the same size in that special case). In general, you could write $r$ as a function of $n$ and it would be strictly decreasing.

Comment: I mention that because you cannot presuppose $n$ and $r$ - most pairs that you choose will lead to impossible situations. Just presuppose $n$ and $R$ and those will together determine $r$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense (in lay terminology, only certain amount of circles of size will fit, correct?)

Comment: Connect the centers of the $n$ externally tangent circles and you will have a regular $n$-gon

Comment: If you choose the number of small circles and the size of the big circle, the size of the small circles is fixed, invariable, set, locked.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will hep you understand how best to form questions and answers. The lingua franca for formulation is [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

For the 'adjacent' circles use : $\delta = 360/n$ where $n$ is the number of circles you want. Then the centers are $c_i = ((R+r)\cos i\delta + \phi, (R+r)\sin i\delta + \phi)$, where $i=0,1,...,n-1$ and $\phi$ is some offset rotation. Note that the small circles will not necessarily touch, but they will touch the large circle.

Edit:
Here's a shadertoy example: 
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/wsfGWj

Comment: I just edited it, realized I had already divided by $n$, so check the corrected version. @AntonLeontyev

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by "offset rotation"? Thank you!

Comment: @AntonLeontyev check the shadertoy example I gave, the offset is literally what rotates the circles around.